# STM32F103 DMA only works in DEBUG Mode

Tags: stm32, dma

I am new to SMT32 development and trying my hands on it. I am using Keil and trying to avoid any HAL driver to understand things better. I am trying to get working DMA to receive data from UART (Actually from a GPS receiver L89H). When I put it in debug mode, everything works as expected, but when not in debug, the program behaves differently and I don't see any data being output using UART1.

**Another strange thing is that, instead of receiving from the GPS chip, If I receive (on UART3) from a terminal manually, then DMA works perfectly. The GPS chip outputs NMEA sentences continuously. So not sure if it is due to the speed of data UART is receiving from the GPS chip.**

**Shall I pause UART or DMA, while processing the received data and start again after the processing is done? What is the right approach of handling continuous data on UART though DMA?**

Below is my code where I initialize and enable UART1, UART3 and DMA1->Channel3

It seems like I am not setting a register or not clearing a register properly (which are being set / cleared in DEBUG mode automatically), but I am unable to catch the error.

````
#include "stm32f10x.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define UART3_DMA_BUFF_LEN              100

uint32_t tickCount = 0;
uint8_t NMEAsentenceRecieved = 0;
volatile uint8_t uart3DMABuffer[UART3_DMA_BUFF_LEN] = {0};

void UART1SendChar(uint16_t chr){
    USART1->DR = chr;
    while(!(USART1->SR & USART_SR_TC));
}

void UART1SendString(const char * str){
    while(*str) {
        UART1SendChar(*str);
        str++;
    }
}

void DMA1_Channel3_IRQHandler(void)
{
    if(DMA1->ISR & DMA_ISR_TCIF3)
    {
        NMEAsentenceRecieved = 1;
    }
    DMA1->IFCR |= DMA_IFCR_CGIF3;
}

void initUART3DMA(){
    //Disable UART3
    USART3->CR1 &= ~USART_CR1_UE;
    //Enable DMA1 Clock
    RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_DMA1EN;
    //Enable DMA for Rx on UART3
    USART3->CR3 |= USART_CR3_DMAR;
    //Setup DMA1 Channel3 for UART3_Rx
    DMA1_Channel3->CCR |= DMA_CCR1_MINC | DMA_CCR1_TCIE | DMA_CCR1_CIRC | DMA_CCR1_TEIE;
    //Set priority to low
    DMA1_Channel3->CCR &= ~(DMA_CCR1_PL_0);
    DMA1_Channel3->CCR &= ~(DMA_CCR1_PL_1);
    //Direction => Read from Peripheral
    DMA1_Channel3->CCR &= ~(DMA_CCR1_DIR);
    DMA1_Channel3->CPAR = (uint32_t) &USART3->DR;
    DMA1_Channel3->CMAR = (uint32_t) uart3DMABuffer;
    DMA1_Channel3->CNDTR = UART3_DMA_BUFF_LEN;
    
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel3_IRQn); 
    NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel3_IRQn, 0);
    
    DMA1_Channel3->CCR |= DMA_CCR3_EN;

    USART3->CR1 |= USART_CR1_UE;
}


void initUART1(void){
    //PA9(TX) and PA10 (RX)
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_USART1EN | RCC_APB2ENR_AFIOEN | RCC_APB2ENR_IOPAEN;
    
    GPIOA->CRH |= GPIO_CRH_MODE9;
    GPIOA->CRH |= GPIO_CRH_CNF9_1;
    GPIOA->CRH &= ~GPIO_CRH_CNF9_0;
    
    /*Configure PA10 as Input floating*/
    GPIOA->CRH &= ~(GPIO_CRH_MODE10);
    GPIOA->CRH |= GPIO_CRH_CNF10_0;
    GPIOA->CRH &= ~GPIO_CRH_CNF10_1;
    
    //Don't remap the default UART1 pins
    AFIO->MAPR &=~ AFIO_MAPR_USART1_REMAP;
    
    //Tx Enable, Rx Enable, Uart Enable
    USART1->CR1 |= USART_CR1_TE | USART_CR1_RE;
    
    USART1->BRR = 0x271; //115200 Baud Rate at APB2 Clock on 72MHz
    
    USART1->CR1 |= USART_CR1_UE;
}

void initUART3(void){
    //PB10(TX) and PB11 (RX)
    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_USART3EN;
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_AFIOEN | RCC_APB2ENR_IOPBEN;
    
    GPIOB->CRH |= GPIO_CRH_MODE10;
    GPIOB->CRH |= GPIO_CRH_CNF10_1;
    GPIOB->CRH &= ~GPIO_CRH_CNF10_0;
    
    /*Configure PB11 as Input floating*/
    GPIOB->CRH &= ~(GPIO_CRH_MODE11);
    GPIOB->CRH |= GPIO_CRH_CNF11_0;
    GPIOB->CRH &= ~GPIO_CRH_CNF11_1;
    
    //Don't remap the default UART3 pins
    AFIO->MAPR &= ~AFIO_MAPR_USART3_REMAP;
    
    //Tx Enable, Rx Enable, Uart Enable, Idling Line Interrupt Enable
    USART3->CR1 |= USART_CR1_TE | USART_CR1_RE;
    
    USART3->BRR = 0x0EA6; //9600 Baud Rate at APB1 Clock on 36MHz
    
    USART3->CR1 |= USART_CR1_UE;
}

void configSysTick(){
    SysTick_Config(SystemCoreClock / 1000); // Tick every 1ms 
}

void SysTick_Handler(void){
    tickCount++;
}

void delayMs(uint32_t ms){
    tickCount = 0;
    while(tickCount < ms){
        __NOP();
    }
}

void parseNMEA(){
    UART1SendString((char *)uart3DMABuffer);
    memset((char *)uart3DMABuffer, 0, UART3_DMA_BUFF_LEN);
}

int main(){
    SystemInit();
    configSysTick();
    initUART1();
    initUART3();
    delayMs(1000);
    
    UART1SendString("Starting an awesome program\n");
    
    delayMs(500);
    
    initUART3DMA();
    
    while(1){
        if(NMEAsentenceRecieved){
            parseNMEA();
            NMEAsentenceRecieved = 0;
        }
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Why are you trying to understand things better by avoiding HAL? Perhaps reading what the HAL does would actually help you understand better.

Comment: The concern here is not HAL, the concern here is where did I make the mistake.

Comment: You can figure it out by reading what your code does differently to HAL.

Comment: When you're debugging in Keil, do you have any watch windows open showing the registers of your UART(s) and/or DMA peripherals?

Comment: Hi @brhans yes I do have USART3 and the DMA1 on the watch windows.. Also I noticed that if I start debugging and after that I stop debugging, still I keep receiving the serial data. But if I start without debugging, no data received, I mean, I see nothing on serial1.

Comment: Hi @brhans another update, it seems like when I receive data on UART3 from a console (by typing a serial console manually), everything works! It does not work when receiving continuously from the GPS chip, it does not work. Not sure if it is something that I need to do with the speed of data received on UART3.